# Custom Alert dialog not centered vertically on Android

Tags: android, dialog, alert

I made a custom alert dialog box to be displayed at the end of my game so that the player can enter its name to save it. The problem is when I call `show()` on the dialog appears but it's not vertically centered! It's a bit lower than it should and no matter what properties I set in the xml or when using `setGravity()`.

I think this is the same problem as [the one mentioned here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HvIcTvxj-Ws), but no one gave a proper answer.

Thanks for your help.

For more details, here is my code:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newrecord,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.shoot));

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);

    newRecDialog = builder.create();
```

And here is the code of the first element of the XML layout of `newrecord.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
 android:padding="10dp"
android:baselineAligned="true">
```

Here is the output screenshot:
[image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://the.niox.free.fr/divers/dialog_offset.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The bug is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11824). The AlertDialog is reserving space for the title/icon panel even where there is neither a title nor an icon.

The fix is, I think, quite simple: it should set the top panel layout to GONE, just as it does for the button panel in the event of there being no buttons. Until that's done, the only workaround is to implement your own Dialog subclass.

Comment: Top Panel? How do you set the top panel layout to gone?

Answer (score 3):

If you implement your own dialog the line *requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)* hides the title panel and the dialog is centered on the screen. Maybe it works with a AlertDialog too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Activity instead of a custom alert for this. You have to set the theme of activity as dialog in the android manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

And you can adjust the activity xml layout as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with any height and width attributes, you must make sure not to alter the height, since it will alter the position, here is a sample.

```
     myProgressDialog.show();           
            float widthPecent = 0.60f;
            //order matters
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        //dont do any adjustments to the height. **************************  <<<<<<<<<<  

            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    
            layoutParams.copyFrom(myProgressDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            int dialogWindowWidth = (int) (displayWidth * widthPecent);
            layoutParams.width = dialogWindowWidth;

 //dont do any changes to the height. **************************  <<<<<<<<<<  

            myProgressDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

layoutParams.height = dialogWindowHeight;  **//comment or remove this line.**

Answer (score 0):

set the attribute on your AlertDialog as `android:gravity="center"` or programmatically as  `setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`. This Gravity is for your layout only not for the display of your mobile. if you use Custom Title its did not look like center vertical.

Comment: I tried all this already and it doesn't work. My XML file is actually the description of the content of the dialog box which I inflate, is this wrong ?

Comment: I cant get you properly. But Any way the content of the view does not affect the gravity. so please post your code. i shall try.

Comment: @NioX5199: can you post your output's Screen shot?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I added a screenshot.

Comment: @NioX5199: try `builder.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` on your java code. It works.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but it tells me that the method setGravity is not defined for  AlertDialog.Builder  :S

Comment: There is no setGravity method for AlertDialog.builder

Comment: maybe Praveen meant dialog.setGravity?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I was having a similar issue.  It appears that it is centered, but it is assuming the AlerterDialog has a title set.  In my case, I just set a title.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `AlertDialog.Builder.setCustomTitle(View);` instead of `setView`? We use it because alert dialog looks a bit better than dialog with empty title.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following line in the xml
    firstly remove that padding line from your xml  and after that

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

after this your dialog will appear in center and if you are using the margin from left etc than remove that and also if you are using that

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

than change it with the

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

after that your dialog will be appear in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
newRecDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the window title.
First create a custom style for your dialog (Make sure to use the parent theme that fits your needs):

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then apply your style to the dialog builder:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newrecord,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.layout.shoot));

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomDialog));
builder.setView(layout);

newRecDialog = builder.create();
```